# Getting a list of folders in a directory

Tags: ruby, directory, directory-listing

How do I get a list of the folders that exist in a certain directory with ruby?

`Dir.entries()` looks close but I don't know how to limit to folders only.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Jordan is close, but `Dir.entries` doesn't return the full path that `File.directory?` expects.  Try this:

```
 Dir.entries('/your_dir').select {|entry| File.directory? File.join('/your_dir',entry) and !(entry =='.' || entry == '..') }
```

Comment: Note that this will get you *all* directories, including hidden ones as well as `'.'` (current directory) and `'..'` (parent of current directory). In most cases, you want to remove at least those two.

Comment: I prefer this one...

`Dir.entries(root).select { |entry| File.directory? File.join(root, entry) and not entry.in? %w[. ..]}`

Comment: But I summited a solution much more clear and succinct, using the `Dir.glob`.

Comment: This is just objectively worse than `Dir.glob()` as seen in the other answer -- I'd strongly recommend just doing that instead of this

Answer (score 119):

I've found this more useful and easy to use:

```
Dir.chdir('/destination_directory')
Dir.glob('*').select {|f| File.directory? f}
```

it gets all folders in the current directory, excluded `.` and `..`.

To recurse folders simply use `**` in place of `*`.

The `Dir.glob` line can also be passed to `Dir.chdir` as a block:

```
Dir.chdir('/destination directory') do
  Dir.glob('*').select { |f| File.directory? f }
end
```

Comment: To recurse folders, you need to use `**/*` in place of `*`.

Comment: Simple and best. Thank you

Comment: Excellent answer.

Answer (score 50):

In my opinion `Pathname` is much better suited for filenames than plain strings.

```
require "pathname"
Pathname.new(directory_name).children.select { |c| c.directory? }
```

This gives you an array of all directories in that directory as Pathname objects.

If you want to have strings

```
Pathname.new(directory_name).children.select { |c| c.directory? }.collect { |p| p.to_s }
```

If `directory_name` was absolute, these strings are absolute too.

Comment: another reason for using `Pathname` is that it automatically removes `.`, `..` and proprietery files like `.DS_Store`

Comment: more tersely: Pathname.new(somepath).children.select(&:directory?)

Answer (score 20):

Recursively find all folders under a certain directory:

```
Dir.glob 'certain_directory/**/*/'
```

Non-recursively version:

```
Dir.glob 'certain_directory/*/'
```

Note: `Dir.[]` works like `Dir.glob`.

Comment: How would you do recursive and non-recursive file find using same logic?  And how recursive and non-recursive file and folders?

Answer (score 6):

With this one, you can get the array of a **full path** to your *directories*, *subdirectories*, *subsubdirectories* in a recursive way.
I used that code to eager load these files inside `config/application` file.

```
Dir.glob("path/to/your/dir/**/*").select { |entry| File.directory? entry }
```

In addition we don't need deal with the boring `.` and `..` anymore. The accepted answer needed to deal with them.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `File.directory?` from the `FileTest` module to find out if a file is a directory. Combining this with `Dir.entries` makes for a nice one(ish)-liner:

```
directory = 'some_dir'
Dir.entries(directory).select { |file| File.directory?(File.join(directory, file)) }
```

**Edit:** Updated per ScottD's correction.

Answer (score 4):

```
directory = 'Folder'
puts Dir.entries(directory).select { |file| File.directory? File.join(directory, file)}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$dir_target = "/Users/david/Movies/Camtasia 2/AzureMobileServices.cmproj/media"

Dir.glob("#{$dir_target}/**/*").each do |f| 
  if File.directory?(f)
    puts "#{f}\n"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Dir.glob('/your_dir').reject {|e| !File.directory?(e)}
```

Comment: Or, instead of `reject !`, `select`

Answer (score 1):

For a generic solution you probably want to use

```
Dir.glob(File.expand_path(path))
```

This will work with paths like `~/*/` (all folders within your home directory).

Comment: Thanks! This is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

We can combine [Borh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15473045/848668) and [johannes' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1899885/848668) to get quite an elegant solution to getting the directory names in a folder.

```
# user globbing to get a list of directories for a path
base_dir_path = ''
directory_paths = Dir.glob(File.join(base_dir_path, '*', ''))

# or recursive version:
directory_paths = Dir.glob(File.join(base_dir_path, '**', '*', ''))

# cast to Pathname
directories = directory_paths.collect {|path| Pathname.new(path) }

# return the basename of the directories
directory_names = directories.collect {|dir| dir.basename.to_s }
```

Answer (score 1):

Only folders ('.' and '..' are excluded):

`Dir.glob(File.join(path, "*", File::SEPARATOR))`

Folders and files:

`Dir.glob(File.join(path, "*"))`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can test each file to see if it is a directory with `FileTest.directory? (file_name)`. See [the documentation for FileTest](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/FileTest.html) for more info.