# Built in way to list directories in a directory in ruby

Tags: ruby, file, directory

Is there a cleaner built-in way to do this?

```
ree> Pathname.new('/path/to').children.select{|e| e.directory?}.map{|d| d.basename.to_s}
 => ["test1", "test2"]
```

Ideally I would like to avoid the `directory?` call

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting a list of folders in a directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1899072/getting-a-list-of-folders-in-a-directory)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Starting from Chandra's answer, depending on whether you need or not the full path, you can use

```
Dir['app/*/']
# => ["app/controllers/", "app/helpers/", "app/metal/", "app/models/", "app/sweepers/", "app/views/"

Dir['app/*/'].map { |a| File.basename(a) }
# => ["controllers", "helpers", "metal", "models", "sweepers", "views"]
```

If you use Ruby >= 1.8.7, Chandra's answer can also be rewritten as

```
Pathname.glob('app/*/').map(&:basename)
# you can skip .to_s unless you don't need to work with strings
# remember you can always use a pathname as string for the most part of Ruby functions
# or interpolate the value
```

Answer (score 9):

```
Pathname.glob("/path/to/*/").map { |i| i.basename.to_s }
```

Comment: This only prints the dir names

Comment: yerp this has my upvote, but I will wait a bit on accepting in case a cleaner solution pops up

Comment: @Chandra Patni, thats what he asked for.