# How can i display the content of public folder in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js

I need to export an XML file. I am able to save the files in the public folder but how do I list the files in this directory. Further, how do I render links such that when clicked by a client browser according file is downloaded.

Comment: how have you saved them?

Answer (score 3):

You can get an array of all file in your public directory using `Dir.entries("public")`.  From there you would simply need to loop through and link to the according name at the root of your application.

So in an ERB file you could use:

```
<ul>
<% Dir.entries("public")[2..-1].each do |file_name| #[2..-1] as the first two will be ".", ".." %>
  <li><%= link_to file_name, "/#{URI.escape(file_name)}" %></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can list the content of public directory from you controller action like this [Built in way to list directories in a directory in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011234/built-in-way-to-list-directories-in-a-directory-in-ruby)

and then use this [file download link in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13164063/file-download-link-in-rails) to create links and download the file.

Hope this will help.